# Raspberry Pi (Jessie) - Multi-Touch Monitor

Tags: raspberry-pi, touch, multi-touch, raspbian, raspberry-pi2

I've got a Iiyama multi-touch monitor that supports up to 10 touch points, however when I plug the USB into the Raspberry Pi it is only recognised as a mouse and the multi touch support is not there.

Google has given no help on this and there doesn't seem to be anything online.

Any help would be appreciated - thanks!

Comment: `lsub` output ? Maybe got a serial device (`ls /dev/ttyU*`)